# Simulate input to STDIN with EOL

Tags: c, bash, user-input, stdin, eol

I am testing a method to simulate a specific input to an application.
This is the application:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int num1;
        char buffer[6] = {0};

        scanf("%d", &num1);
        read(0, buffer, 6);

        printf("num1 = %d\n", num1);

        for(num1=0; num1 < 6; num1++)
        {
                printf("%02X\n", buffer[num1]);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

I am trying to simulate the input using the following bash command:

```
echo -ne "1337\\x0A\\x31\\x02\\x03\\x04\\x05\\x06" | ./test
```

The output I get is the following:

```
num1 = 1337
00
00
00
00
00
00
```

As you can see, the buffer was not filled with values passed to the STDIN.

**EDIT:**
**The function below is only used to illustrate an idea of input automation in mixed i/o functions, I got this function by reverse engineering a binary file, is it possible to automate the input ?**

I appreciate your help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening here?

- `echo` is making a write with exactly as many characters you put in the command line (as you use `-n` flag it doesn't output a final `\n` char).
- you are using `scanf()` on a pipe, so it makes a full buffer read first, and then scans the buffer for an integer.  It does a `n = read(0, buffer, BUFSIZ);` returning 11 as the number of characters read to scanf and then scanf scans the buffer, returning `1337` as the number read and leaving all the characters past it into the buffer.
- then you do a `read(0, buffer, 6);` that returns 0 and the buffer is not initialized with data.
- then you print the previous, uninitialized buffer contents to stdout.

fifos (or pipes) behave quite different than terminals on input.  The terminal driver just makes a read to complete when you push the `enter` key, making read to get the actual number of characters read by one input line.  When you do this with a fifo, the reader process is blocked until enough characters (the actual number requested by read) is fed to the process and then that number (actually the requested number of characters) is returned by read.

If you had the precaution of checking the `read(2)` return value, you should get the actual number of read chars (that should be `0` as the `scanf(3)`
 has eaten the complete buffer as it is smaller than `BUFSIZ` constant, in the first read)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!. Can we say as a conclusion that it is impossible to automate the input to the function above because scanf will read the whole stdin buffer ? Do you have any other ideas to pass the data without pipes ?

Comment: It will try to read.  Normally, when input comes from a terminal device, it only gets as much input up to the newline char (terminal even translates ASCII CR to ASCII LF to comply with UNIX convention)  In this case, is the terminal driver who decides the amount of data to return.  This is the reason of needing always to check the return value of `read(2)` syscall, because you don't always get as much data as you requested.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing `scanf()` ([section 3 man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)) and `read()` ([section 2 man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read)).  The `scanf()` series of functions perform *buffered* reads and writes.  The section 2 `read()` is unbuffered.  The bytes you are trying to read with `read()` have already been read and put into the buffer `scanf()` is using.

If you comment out your `scanf()` line, and change your command to

```
    echo -ne "\\x0A\\x31\\x02\\x03\\x04\\x05\\x06" | ./test
```

you will get

```
num1 = 0
0A
31
02
03
04
05
```

So just use the buffered functions or the unbuffered functions.  Pick one.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable information. Actually this code was not written by me. I have the compiled binary only, But I reversed it to a simple form to the snippet that you can see above. I was wondering if it is possible to automate this even if they functions are mixed.

Comment: @xedar, If you reverse engineer something, don't use `scanf()` that will buffer all the input in the stdio buffer and then makes `read()` to return 0 bytes (as there's  a pipe here and echo simply feed all the bytes you passed to it to the output).  You have not checked the return value of read to check for this and suppose read is reading 6 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Never mix stdio functions like scanf with low level io functions like read. Stdio maintains a buffer for efficiency and if any extra data is available when you call scanf it is likely going to read it to fill the buffer.

Use fread instead of read. Also, don't forget to check the return values of these functions.

Comment: Thank you Joni, actually I didn't write the application. This is reversed from binary and I am trying to automate the input.